# How to enable Youtube Oauth2 using django-allauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, django-allauth

Google is in the list of providers in allauth, but youtube is not.  However [in the google docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) I see specific urls to be used for oauth2 for youtube.

Should I use the oauth2 base in allauth to build out my youtube oauth2 connection or am I missing something and the Google provider does what I need?